# Simple code to change '^' to Math.pow() in java

Tags: java, math, calculator

I am using java's ScriptEngine to do simple math calculations.
When I give it 2^2 it gives me 0 instead of 4. Can anyone give me a simple conversion for using '^' to Math.pow?

Comment: is the `^` in code or in an input?

Comment: `^` refers to the bitwise `XOR` operator if you're curious, thats why it returns 0. 2 XOR itself is 0.

Comment: You know that `^` is bitwise xor in Java, right?

Comment: If it's an input you could do a loop checking if it's a number, the ^, or another character. If it's a number, append it to a int. If ^, start a second int, and if it's something else: delete it or give an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "conversion". Do you want to rewrite a string, or do you just want to know how to use the Math.pow() function, or....

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an editor and correct the code.  What you have sounds like it's simply wrong.

Maybe a regex in IntelliJ could do it easily: replace `(\\d+)(^)(\\d+)`  with    `Math.pow($1, $2)`

The `^` character has a special meaning in regular expressions.  You might have to escape it to make it a character.

Comment: The idea was to make a graphing program and it was easier to use the ScriptEngine than to write my own, but I did write a simple method to do so and it's working fine.